# Indefinite quantity of a class member variable(C++)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list, nodes

The C++ program I'm working on is designed to create a custom doubly Linked List class in C++ by utilizing an indefinite number of node struct pointers with a data value and two pointers inside.  That's the premise of this program.  Can't use the STL LinkedList class, have to make my own.

This being said, how do you create a class member variable that doesn't have a specific amount of pointers to nodes?  I don't want to initialize fifty nodes when declaring the class, but then only use ten of them.  and at the same time, I don't want to initialize only 5 and then have to use more than that 5.  Is there a way to dynamically add node pointers to a linked list class in C++, when node pointers are considered a member variable?

Am I even going about this the right way?  And if so, how will I go about doing this?

Comment: No, you are complicating issues.  Let one node point to the next node, called a *singly linked list*.  If you are really aggressive, you can add another pointer that points to the previous node.  Nodes only need one or two pointers, not an array, not yet at least.

Comment: So I just need the one node in my class, then?  Because using a class here is a requirement on my assignment.

Comment: @TreyBrumley Your list class only needs a pointer to the first node in case of the singly linked list and additionally one to the last one if doubly linked. The rest gets handled by the nodes. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) might help you understand the basic concept.

Comment: You need at least two classes.  One is the container or `List` class, the other is a `Node` class.  The container class has a pointer to the first Node.  Optionally, it may contain a pointer to the last Node.  See the drawings in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Picture this:

```
+----------+-------+------+  
| Previous | Data  | Next |  
| Node     | Field | Node |  
+----------+-------+------+
```

A node with two link fields and a data field.
*(Linked lists are always easier to understand when you draw them.)*

We could have two of them:

```
+----------+-------+------+  
| Previous | Data  | Next |  
| Node     | Field | Node |  
+----------+-------+------+  
    ^                  |  
    |                  V  
+----------+-------+------+  
| Previous | Data  | Next |  
| Node     | Field | Node |  
+----------+-------+------+
```

The `Previous Node` field of the 2nd node points to the first.  The first node has no *predecessors*, so it's `Previous Node` field is empty.

Similarly, the `Next Node` field of the first node points to the 2nd node.  The 2nd node has no *successor*, so the `Next Node` field of the 2nd node is empty.

This is what I believe the requirements want:  a doubly linked list using pointers.

**Edit 1: Three nodes**

```
+----------+-------+------+  
| Previous | Data  | Next |  
| Node     | Field | Node |  
+----------+-------+------+  
    ^                  |  
    |                  V  
+----------+-------+------+  
| Previous | Data  | Next |  
| Node     | Field | Node |  
+----------+-------+------+  
    ^                  |  
    |                  V  
+----------+-------+------+  
| Previous | Data  | Next |  
| Node     | Field | Node |  
+----------+-------+------+
```

As you can see, to visit (traverse) the nodes in a *forward* manner, you follow the link field of one node to get to the next node.  Similarly, to go in a *backwards* manner, you follow the `Previous Node` link to get to a node's predecessor.

A nice issue about the links is that you only need to change the link fields in order to insert a node in the *middle* of the list.  Drawing of the insertion processes is left as an exercise for the reader.

**Edit 2:  The Container Class**
The Linked List is a *container* of *nodes*.  For simple implementations, the Container class should not be a Node.

The Container *has-a* pointer to the first node and optionally a pointer to the last node:

```
+------+-------+  
| Last | First |  
| Node |  Node |  
+------+-------+  
  |        |  
  |        +---------------+  
  |                        |
  |                        V
  |  +----------+-------+------+  
  |  | Previous | Data  | Next |  
  |  | Node     | Field | Node |  
  |  +----------+-------+------+  
  |      ^                  |  
  |      |                  V  
  |  +----------+-------+------+  
  |  | Previous | Data  | Next |  
  |  | Node     | Field | Node |  
  |  +----------+-------+------+  
  |      ^                  |  
  |      |                  V  
  |  +----------+-------+------+  
  |  | Previous | Data  | Next |  
  +->| Node     | Field | Node |  
     +----------+-------+------+
```

By using a *container* class, you don't need to worry about an using an empty node as the first node.  Here, we use a simple pointer to point to the first node.  Additionally, there is a pointer to the last node.

The pointer to the last node speeds up the operation of appending nodes to the list.  Without this pointer, you would have to traverse all the nodes to find the last one, which takes a lot of time.

Comment: @nonsensickle:  As I stated in my comments, linked lists are always better to understand when drawn. :-)